# When does a directive created with isolated scope re-renders in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive to render google map using google maps Javascript API and I'm passing the values such as center, zoom level, and object with latitude and longitude as attributes to the this newly created directive like :

```html
<google-map center="centervalue" zoomlevel="zoomvalue" co-ordinates="locationObject">
```

and here is directive code snippet :

```js
angular
    .module('locationApp')
    .directive('googleMap', showMap);

function showMap() {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template:'<div id="map"></div>',
        scope :{
            list:'=markers',
            zoom:"=zoom",
            center:"=center"
        }
    };
    return directive;
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element[0].style.minHeight = "400px";
        element[0].style.height = "100%";
        element[0].style.width = "100%";

    
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: scope.zoom,
        center: scope.center
        }
        
        scope.$watch('list',function(newValue,oldValue){

             var mapOptions = {
                                zoom: scope.zoom,
                                center: scope.center
                              }

            element[0].innerHTML ="";
            var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);

            for (var index = 0; index < newValue.length; index++) {
            var loc = newValue[index];
    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:{lat: parseFloat(loc.latitude), lng: parseFloat(loc.longitude)},
            map: map
            });

             var content = "Pincode : " + loc.pincode +", Area name : "+ loc.area +"[Lat,Lon] are : ["+loc.latitude+","+loc.longitude+"]";   
         
             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
         
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
             return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
             };
             })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

        }

    });

    scope.$watch('center',function(newValue,oldValue){

             var mapOptions = {
                                zoom: scope.zoom,
                                center: scope.center
                              }

            element[0].innerHTML ="";
            var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);

            var loc = newValue;
    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:{lat: parseFloat(loc.lat), lng: parseFloat(loc.lng)},
            map: map
            });

             var content = "Latitude :" + loc.lat +", Longitude : "+loc.lng;   
         
             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
         
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
             return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
             };
             })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

    
        });
    
    }
}
```

I want to know that if I change the locationObject or any passed value on some event in parent controller , will my directive re-render ? Currently it is not re-rendering , what is the mechanism to achieve the case that when the passed values have been changed , the directive template should re-render with newer values which are passed to directive .I'm using angular version 1.5 .Any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: usually for rerender something in angular you can use "$scope.$apply()", but i think it would be nice to see the inner code of the directive. may be plunker could be usefull...

Comment: I have used react a bit , in react we have a render method in every component which gets called automatically whenever there is state change to props passed in from upper component to child component . Is there really no other declarative way of doing this , while setting up the directive ?
@happyZZR1400

Comment: that is why is better  to see the code of directive definition - it will be more clear how to help

Comment: @happyZZR1400 added directive definiton code snippet .

Comment: @happyZZR1400 currently I'm using watch over the list attribute to listen for changes and re-plotting the markers on map . Can we do this without a watch and listener in some kind of declarative way ?

Comment: may be "$onChanges" hook is what you need...